# How to update children with parent in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a complex class and when I update data in View and save it to database, Entity saves it twice child class data.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Children> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Children
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

 var v = context.Parent.Include(c=>c.Children);
 return View(v)
```

View file includes this

```
@model Parent
<input asp-for=Parent.Name >
for(int i; i<Model.Child.Count();i++)
{
    <input asp-for=Parent.Child[1].Name />
}
```

I very simplified the classes..
if change Parent and children's name in the browser(View), It updates parent name but insert new name for children, rather than update children's name. Everytime i change children name, it adds new children to database.

```
public void Save(Parent parent)
{
   if (Parent.ID== 0)
   {
       context.Parent.Add(parent);
   }
   else
   {
       Paret dbEntry = context.Parent.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID== parentID);
       if (dbEntry != null)
       {
                dbEntry.ID= parent.ID;
                dbEntry.Name= parent.NAme;
                dbEntry.Children = parent.Children;
        }
     }

     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: What do you exect `dbEntry.Children = parent.Children;` to do?

Comment: Well, unless I missed it, there is no `Child` in your model, and your loop isn't really looping through the items - re: you're index is always `[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `dbEntry.Children = parent.Children;` line adding the children as new children, not updating the existing children.

You can overcome this problem as follows:

```
public void Save(Parent parent)
{ 
    if (Parent.ID== 0)
    {
       context.Parent.Add(parent);
    }
    else
    {
       Parent dbEntry = context.Parent.Inlcude(p => p.Children).FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID== parentID);

       if (dbEntry != null)
       {
            dbEntry.ID= parent.ID;
            dbEntry.Name= parent.NAme;

            dbEntry.Children.Clear() // It will clear the children before adding the updated version of the children.

            dbEntry.Children = parent.Children;
        }
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```